# eclipse(ADT) crashing when writing line include "R."

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, crash

I downloaded the **Android Development Tools** SDK which include `Eclipse` and `SDK`.
The `Eclipse` IDE crashes when i try to write a line that include **"R."**, like:

```
EditTex Password= (EditText)FindViewById(R.id.pass)
```

It won't show the error, it just crashes.

Comment: I think `R.id.pass` is right. I may be wrong I'm not an android expert.

Comment: Could you post your Eclipse Log: `Help -> About Eclipse -> Configuration Details -> View Error Log`

Comment: A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x56ca89fd, pid=7543, tid=3075663552
 JRE version: 7.0_25-b30
 Java VM: OpenJDK Client VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-x86 )
 Problematic frame:
 C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x539fd]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x1d

 Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
 instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/

Answer (score 1):

You should use: `R.id.yourControlId`

In the autogenerated class `R` are you're ID's stored for multiple things like your resources; images/strings etc..

To get your images from your drawable folder: `R.drawable.image`

To get your string from your strings.xml: `R.string.hello_world`

So you should do this instead: `EditText Password = (EditText)FindViewById(R.id.pass);`

Comment: yes, i'm sorry. i forgot to write the id in the post, but it isn't the problem. when i type "R." the eclipse window just get closed

Comment: @user3274665 Try re-installing and re-setting every thing up

Comment: I tried it before. it happens again, and in two diffrent computers, one using linux 32 bit and the second linux 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have the problem, too, seems to be a bug in the openjdk in connection with the ADT. This has nothing to do with the code you write in eclipse. It can be triggered in more ways. And it seems that it is no problem with eclipse itself, because it is no Java-Exception but the javavm that segfaults. Looking for a workaround myself atm.

Edit: May be this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404776
Edit2: And this here may be a workaround: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404776#c7